# How to validate that an array with dates is arranged newer to older and vice versa

Tags: javascript

I am still very much a newbie to JS and had a question for which I cannot find an answer for.

I have an array such as:

```
[
                2000-03-22 12:00 AM
                2000-03-21 12:00 AM
                2000-03-17 12:00 AM
                2000-03-17 12:00 AM
                2000-03-15 12:00 AM
                2000-03-15 12:00 AM
                2000-03-15 12:00 AM
                2000-03-11 12:00 AM
]
```

The actual array is much longer. I need to do a for loop (if best) to check if the dates are arranged in a newer to older or older to newer manner. I don't need to sort them using JS, I already have the list sorted by default.

I have done validations between two dates before, however, I am not sure how to approach an entire array of dates.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you know the list is sorted, could you just take the first two and compare them with `<`?  If  `arr[0] < arr[1]` then the list is sorted with oldest date first, else newest date first?

Comment: This kind of looks like a homework assignment.  But - if you've compared two dates, just do that over and over in a loop until you reach the end, or until you find two dates where the second is before the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like all you need to do is compare 2 dates (if they're already sorted). The first and last should do it.

```js
let dates = [
  "2000-03-22 12:00 AM",
  "2000-03-21 12:00 AM",
  "2000-03-17 12:00 AM",
  "2000-03-17 12:00 AM",
  "2000-03-15 12:00 AM",
  "2000-03-15 12:00 AM",
  "2000-03-15 12:00 AM",
  "2000-03-11 12:00 AM"
]

let howSorted = arr => new Date(arr[0]) < new Date(arr[arr.length - 1]) ? 'ascending' : 'descending'

console.log(howSorted(dates))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array with the differences between the dates:

```js
const differences = Array(dates.length-1).fill().map((_, i) => dates[i+1] - dates[i]);
```

and then just check if either it's all positive (old to new) or negative (new to old)

```js
const isToNew = differences.every(n => n >= 0);
const isToOld = differences.every(n => n <= 0);
```

of course, if neither are true, it means your dates are not sorted correctly

---

If you're confident they're already in order and don't care to verify this, then you can simply just sort the first and last date as shown in the other answer.